# shell script: search and replace multiple lines but keep some part of string

Tags: regex, perl, shell, sed

Im trying to replace part of a text file that looks like this

```
[stuff before]
<!--WEIRD_SPECIAL_COMMENT_BEGIN-->
[stuff here, most to be removed but everything within $TEXT-WANT-TO-KEEP$ should be kept]
<!--WEIRD_SPECIAL_COMMENT_END-->
[stuff after]
```

but between WEIRD_SPECIAL_COMMENT_BEGIN and WEIRD_SPECIAL_COMMENT_END there's some text that I want to keep. The text is always enclosed in $ signs.

So really what I want is to keep the text enclosed in $ signs, delete everything else between WEIRD_SPECIAL_COMMENT_BEGIN and WEIRD_SPECIAL_COMMENT_END and paste the text within $...$ with
NEW_TEXT_1 before and NEW_TEXT_2. The end result I have in mind looks like this:

```
[stuff before]
<NEW_TEXT_1>
[TEXT_I_WANT_TO_KEEP]
<NEW_TEXT_2>
[stuff after]
```

I'm new to working in the shell and can't figure out how to do this using the `sed`command. Any help much appreciated.

**Update:**

my file is quite messy, but a simple working example might be a latex document

```
[stuff before]
\begin{enumerate}
\item bla bla 
\item bla bla
\item $x = y$
\end{enumerate}
[stuff after]
```

Result I have in mind could look like this

```
[stuff before]
\begin{equation}
x = y
\end{equation}
[stuff after]
```

Comment: Can `$TEXT-WANT-TO-KEEP$` span across multiple lines?

Comment: Please include your current code.

Comment: Can you have loose `$` in the target text that will mess up your format? Such as `foo costs $12, $TEXT_TO_KEEP$ qwerty`.

Comment: I updated the question with a simple example

Comment: If your format is Latex, should you not be using a proper parser for this?

Comment: the format is not always latex, that's why I'm looking for something more general.

Comment: If the format varies, a single solution might not always be bug free. I think the simplest solution is to use a flip-flop to catch the begin/end blocks, and then a simple regex match to capture the strings you want to keep and print them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my shot at it:

```
cat stuff.txt | \
    sed 's/<\!--.*BEGIN-->/<NEW_TEXT_1>/' | \
    sed 's/<\!--.*END-->/<NEW_TEXT_2>/' | \
    sed 's/^.*\($.*$\).*$/\1/'
```

---

edit: Attempt #2, using a bash script!

```
#!/bin/bash

IN=0
while read s; do 

    if [ "$s" = "\\begin{equation}" ]; then
        IN=1
        continue
    fi

    if [ "$IN" = "1" ]; then 

        if [ "$s" = "\\end{equation}" ]; then
            IN=0 
            continue
        else
            echo $s | sed 's/.*\(\$.*\$\).*/\1/'
        fi

    else
        echo $s
    fi

done < stuff.txt;
```

edit2: attempt 3 ;) This bash script is starting to get pretty ugly, but I wanted to see if I could make it work, so here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash

#backslashes and braces don't match well in bash string comparisons.
#so, lets replace them with better identifiers. 
cat stuff2.txt | sed 's/\\\(begin\|end\){enumerate}/XXXX\1/' > tmpfile

IN=0
while read s; do 


    if [ "$s" = "XXXXbegin" ]; then
        IN=1
        continue
    fi

    if [ "$IN" = "1" ]; then 

        if [ "$s" = "XXXXend" ]; then
            IN=0 
            continue
        else
                    #sed -n means don't print anything
                    # but the /p at the end means print matches

            echo $s | sed -n 's/.*\$\(.*\)\$.*/\1/p'
        fi

    else
        echo $s
    fi

done < tmpfile

rm -f tmpfile
```

Comment: This will apply the deletion on the entire input, not just the stuff between the begin/end tags.

Comment: Well - I'm certain that a sed master can do it in only sed, but I think in bash so I wrote a bash script :) hope that helps somewhat..

Comment: when I apply the bash script to the simple latex example given above all it does is remove the backslashes?

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine being able to do this with a simple `grep` or `sed`. These are lined based tools, and as such. I can imagine a simple script that loops through your file:

```
while read line
do
    # Magic happens here
done < $myfile
```

Now, all we have to figure out what that magic should be...

Even easier is an awk script that can do the same thing:

```
awk '{ #Magic stuff happens here }' $myfile
```

An awk script runs on an *implied loop*.

Let's use a variable to track whether or not you're in that *weird stuff*:

```
awk '{
    line = $0
    if ( $0 = "<!--WEIRD_SPECIAL_COMMENT_BEGIN-->" ) {
        weird_stuff = 1
    }
    if ( $0 = "<!--WEIRD_SPECIAL_COMMEND_END-->" ) {
        weird_stuff = 0
    }
    if ( weird_stuff = 1 ) {
        munge line...
    }
    print line
}' $myfile
```

Now, we have to figure out how to munge the line. Awk can handle regular expressions, but it isn't quite as rich as Perl in the way it can handle stuff like this.

Can there be more than one thing surrounded in `$` in your line? If so, we may be able to use the `index` command to look for the `$`

```
awk '{
     line = $0
     if ( $0 = "<!--WEIRD_SPECIAL_COMMENT_BEGIN-->" ) {
         weird_stuff = 1
     }
     if ( $0 = "<!--WEIRD_SPECIAL_COMMEND_END-->" ) {
         weird_stuff = 0
     }
     if ( weird_stuff != 1 ) { # This is not in the weird stuff. Print the line
         print $0
         next
    }
    # Weird Stuff at this point forward
    first_char = index( $0, "$")
    if ( first_char = 0 ) {
        next    # Nothing to print
    }
    subline = substr( $0, first_char + 1 )  # Remove up to the $
    second_char = index( subline, "$" )
    if ( second_char = 0 ) {
        next    # No second "$" found. Nothing to print
    }
    print substr( subline, 1, $second_char - 1)
}' $myfile
```

My `awk` is really, really rusty. I had stopped using `awk` when I discovered Perl back when Perl was in version 3. So, I cannot guarantee whether or not this program works. I'm not even testing it.

However, it does give you an idea how you could handle your issue. I could have done something similar with a:

```
while read line
do
    # Magic stuff happens here...
done < $myfile
```

If I did that, I could have used `sed` which would have been able to pluck out the `$...$` from the rest of the input string in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Wait. Perl is okay? I just realized it was in your tags. Your title said "Shell Script". To most people, that means `awk` is fine, but Perl is not.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);
use File::stat;

my $weird_flag = 0;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    chomp $line;
    if ( $line =~ /\\begin{enumerate}/ ) {
        $weird_flag = 1;
        say "$line";
        next;
    }
    if ( $line =~ /\\end{enumerate}/ ) {
        $weird_flag = 1;
        say "$line";
        next;
    }
    if ( not $weird_flag ) {
        say "$line";
    }
    else {
        if ( $line =~ s/.*?\$(.*)\$.*/$1/ ) {
            say "$line";
        }
    }
}
__DATA__
[stuff before]
\begin{enumerate}
\item bla bla 
\item bla bla
\item $x = y$
\end{enumerate}
[stuff after]
```

Comment: I can't see how applying this to the simple example provides the solution?

Comment: I've just changed it to match your other example. I can't do any more than that. It basically the same algorithm as my [awk solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22253176/368630), but because I'm more familiar with Perl, I spent time testing it. If you want to know how this solution works, see my `awk explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/<!--WEIRD_SPECIAL_COMMENT_BEGIN-->/,/<!--WEIRD_SPECIAL_COMMENT_END-->/{//d;s/[^$]*\$\([^$]*\).*/[\1]/;i\<NEW_TEXT_1>' -e 'a\<NEW_TEXT_2>' -e '}' file
```

Comment: this gives me error message "extra characters after \ at the end of i command"

Comment: @SebastianBarfort are you using GNU sed?

Comment: I was using mac's sed, but it actually works using GNU sed. Thanks a lot!